# Spring Boot picks up non-profiled implementations of an interface along with profiled ones when an active profile is set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been doing some illustrative programming for a course I'm doing on Udemy, intended to show principles of Spring Boot dependency injection using Profiles and Qualifiers.

There's a Test that has an `@Autowired` controller. In the Controller it specifies `@ActiveProfiles("EN")` for the English `GreetingService`, and in the constructor it has a qualifier `@Qualifier("i18nService")` on the `GreetingService` parameter so that the constructor for the Controller wires in an i18nService English GreetingService.

Trouble is there's also a `GreetingService` that has no `@Profile` set, and unless I specify a `@Profile` on it then Boot will attempt to wire both the English i18nService *and* the default, non-profiled version, that has no Qualifier or Profile set.

Why is this happening? Is there a good reason for it? Is there a convenient way to specify "If there's a specified component you've been told explicitly to wire in, and another more generic one that you haven't, wire in the one you've been told to wire in & leave the other well alone"?

Code is at https://github.com/Skiamakhos/Spring6DI/tree/main if folks want a look.

Comment: Note that if I do specify a profile on the non-profiled service, the problem goes away, but, should we have to do that? Potentially that's a lot of classes to annotate if we're talking about a big system one is maintaining.

Comment: Beans without an `@Profile` (or whatever condition) are **always created** also the `@ActiveProfile` annotation is an testing annotation and is for use in tests **not** for use in main code. YOu can mark your non profile limited implementation with `@Primary` which means if no dedicated candidate can be found use this one.

Comment: "If no profile is active, a default profile is enabled. The name of the default profile is `default` and it can be tuned using the `spring.profiles.default` Environment property.." ..from [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)

Comment: @M.Deinum - can you redo that as an answer rather than as a comment? I think that's worked, & deserves proper credit for answering the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `@Profile` annotation restricts the bean's creation, in the absence of `@Profile`, and with the presence of `@Service`, Spring will create the bean and add it to the application context.  Now, it's available for auto wiring just like any other bean of the same type.

Looking at your use-case, it looks like you're creating support for i18n.  I don't think you want to use Profiles to drive this behavior.  For one reason, with each new language that you want to support, you'll have to create an entirely new instance of your GreetingService.  Spring has built-in support for i18n; simply create `message` files for each language you want to support, e.g.  Read up on their documentation for [MessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) and [Spring Internationalization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-internationalization.html).

Comment: Yeah, to be fair this was just an exercise from Spring Framework Guru's "Spring Framework 6 & Spring Boot 3 Beginner to Guru" course, rather than any kind of use in the field - there're definitely better ways to go about this that avoid what's essentially an out of control multi-classing smell. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Beans without an `@Profile` (or whatever condition for that matter) are always created.

You can mark your non-profile limited implementation with `@Primary` which means if no dedicated candidate (through name or qualifier) can be found use this one.